# Read 2d array in a loop char by char

Tags: c, arrays, char, malloc, 2d

How can I read a 2D array with perfect memory allocation char by char?

Example: 
"Book" allocates exactly the length of that word.
I think I could use the function getchar() but I don t know-how.

Comment: can you give a clearer example, it seems like you just want someone to write the code for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [strlen](https://beginnersbook.com/2017/11/c-strlen-function/) to get the length of the string (string must have a null byte in the end).

Then [realloc](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/c_standard_library/c_function_realloc.htm) can be used to change the size of the allocated array if necessary.